# Syntax to edit post_max_size value in php.ini with Terminal?

Tags: php, file-upload, php-ini

I am attempting to use Terminal on Mac to edit the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` values in my file. I thought of typing something like `post_max_size = 50M` into Terminal, but I'm not sure.

**What is the correct syntax to use to update these values in Terminal?**

The screenshot below shows what I've gotten to in my Terminal so far. 
[image: screenshot from my mac]

Comment: Search for the existing line and then amend its value.

Comment: So all I do is over-write the value with a new one? Is there a 'Save' command necessary after that or can I just exit Terminal?

Comment: I would suggest you do a save. I would also suggest you look got a simpler editor. Probably a gui based editor rather than a unix line editor.